# php Array specific printout

Tags: php, arrays, date, sum

I have an array that looks like:

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2013
        [1] => 12
        [2] => 52
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2013
        [1] => 12
        [2] => 51
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2013
        [1] => 12
        [2] => 50
    )
```

And so on...
This data represent Year, Month, Week.
There are also a table of data that contains some int value for each line.
ex.(2013-12-50 76), so i can make it on fourth position [3].

I need to make a page with 3 drop-down boxes, 3 check boxes and a submit button, so when I
chose in this drop-downs, ex. first one:Year=2012(checked), second:Month=10(checked), third:Week=null(unchecked) and press the submit button I get the Sum of Data(not dates) for 2012-10.

How do operate with this array in the right way to be able to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make an attempt; post when\if you get stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For drop downs:

```
echo "<select name='year'>";
for($x = 0; $x< count($array); $x++){
   echo "<option value='".$array[$x][0]."'>".$array[$x][0]."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

just change the index for which of the inner arrays element you want include in the drop down

similar for checkboxes

```
for($x = 0; $x< count($array); $x++){
   echo "<input type='checkbox' name='element[$x]'  value='".$array[$x][4]."' ".(isset($array[$x][4])?"checked ='checked'":"").">;
}
```